# C/C++ unused inline function undefined reference

Tags: c++, c, linux, gcc, ld

Consider the following code (this is not pthread specific; other examples, such as those involving the realtime library, exhibit similar behavior):

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <pthread.h>

inline void foo() {
    static cpu_set_t cpuset;
    pthread_setaffinity_np(pthread_self(), sizeof(cpu_set_t), &cpuset);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { }
```

This is a valid program in C and in C++.  So I save the contents of this to `testc.c` and `testcpp.cpp` and try to build.

When I build in `C++` I get no error.  When I build in `C` I get an undefined reference error.  Now, this error occurs in `-O1` and in `-O3`.  Is there anyway to instruct gcc to do the right thing (see that `foo` is unused and skip the requirement for a definition of `pthread_setaffinity_np`)?

EDIT: I thought it was obvious from context, but the error message is:

```
/tmp/ccgARGVJ.o: In function `foo':
testc.c:(.text+0x17): undefined reference to `pthread_setaffinity_np'
```

Note that since `foo` isn't being referenced in the main path, `g++` correctly ignores the function entirely but `gcc` does not.

EDIT 2: Let me try this one more time.  The function `foo`, and the subsequent call to `pthread_setaffinity_np`, is unused.  The main function is empty.  Just look at it!  Somehow, `g++` figured out that `foo` did not need to be included, and subsequently the build process did not trip up when we intentionally omitted `-lpthread`  (and checking the exported symbols with `nm` confirms that neither `foo` nor reference to `pthread_setaffinity_np` were needed).  The resultant output from `gcc` didn't pick up on that fact.

I am asking this question because the C++ and the C frontends seem to give different results on the same input.  This doesn't seem to be an `ld` issue prima facie because I would expect both paths to give the same linking error, which is why I emphasized that it seems to be a compiler issue.  If both C++ and C gave problems, then yes I would agree that its a linking issue.

Comment: **Whenever you get a compiler error, always paste the exact error in your question**.

Comment: @Seth - Either that or read the error carefully and figure out what it's trying to tell you.  (After all, it's only words.)  This is a skill that will serve the questioner well.

Comment: @asve well even if you figure it out, if you post a question on SO, you still need to include the exact error :)

Comment: @Seth @asveikau I erroneously presumed that, given the context, the only possibilities could be `pthread_setaffinity_np` and `pthread_self`, but I made it explicit now

Comment: @Foo are you ever going to use in when you compile it as C? Or do you want the compiler to figure out if it's used by itself? I don't think there's a way to do that.

Comment: You need to link with `-lpthread`.

Comment: @Seth for the record, the inline function was in a header that was designed to be C and C++ compatible.  This example was a very small snipped designed to emphasize the point.

Comment: Inline functions in headers should always be `static inline`, because any function defined in a header should have static linkage. In C++ this may not be a big deal but in C it's very important.

Comment: @R, I completely disagree, this is not the right way to use `inline` in C and this is not the way that it is intended in the standard. You'd just have to have an instantiation in one compilation unit that's it.

Comment: Your program is not correct C. `inline` functions in C can't have static variables.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, apparently your program contains an error: you declare and call function `pthread_setaffinity_np`, but you never define it. Apparently you forgot to supply the library that contains the definition. This is an error in both C and C++.

In other words, this is *not* a valid program in C and in C++. It violates the One Definition Rule of C++ (and whatever the similar rule is called in C).

The rest depends on whether the compiler will catch this error and issue a diagnostic message for it. While formally the compiler is supposed to catch it, in reality linking errors are not always caught by the compilation process (in extended sense of the term, i.e. including linking as well).

Whether they are caught or not might depend on many factors. In this particular case the factor that matters is apparently the difference between the properties of inline functions of C and C++ languages. (And yes, they are really different between C and C++). I would guess that in C++ mode the compiler decided that this inline function does not need the actual body, while in C mode it decided to generate the body anyway.

So, again, if this program, somehow successfully compiles in some circumstances, it is only because you got lucky. You seem to believe that a function that is not called is supposed to be "ignored entirely". Neither C nor C++ make such guarantees. Assuming that the definition of `pthread_setaffinity_np` is indeed missing, your program is invalid in both C and C++. For this reason, the compiler that refused to compile it is actually the one with the correct behavior.

Taking the above into account, you might want to ask yourself whether you really care about why you got different error reports in C and C++ modes. If you do, it will require some research into the internal mechanics of that specific implementation and won't have much to do with the languages themselves.

Comment: Sometimes we come across unexpected behaviors.  Some people just hack a solution and move on.  I want to understand why I was surprised :)

Comment: Just to note some additional aspect why this is not a correct *C* program: in C `inline` functions are not allowed to declare `static` variables.

Comment: @Jensen is there a way to force GCC to enforce this rule (or at least give me some sort of warning)

Comment: @Foo Bah: `gcc -std=c99` will give you a warning. `gcc -std=c99 -pedantic-errors` will give you an error. By default gcc runs its own version of wildly extended C99-based version of C language where quite a few non-standard extensions are accepted without even a warning.

Answer (score 6):

In C, the `inline` keyword **does not affect the linkage** of the function. Thus `foo` has external linkage, and cannot be optimized out because it might be called from another translation unit. If the compiler/assembler put functions in their own individual sections and the linker is able to discard unneeded function sections at link time, it might be able to avoid a linking error, but to be correct, since this program references `pthread_setaffinity_np`, it must contain a definition for that function somewhere anyway, i.e. you must use `-lpthread` or equivalent.

In C++, `inline` functions have <strike>internal</strike> *some weird pseudo-external* linkage by default, so gcc optimized it out. *See the comments for details.*

In short, the lack of an error in certain configurations is a failure of gcc to diagnose an invalid program. It's not the behavior you should expect.

The other lesson you should take away from this is that C and C++ are nowhere near the same thing. Choose which one you're writing and stick to it! Don't try to write code that's "interchangeable" between the two or you're likely to make it subtly incorrect in both...

Comment: I completely forgot about that.  Based on your reply, I tried declaring it as `static inline` and the C program behaved as I would expect

Comment: GCC has some non-standard options that could be used as well, such as `__attribute__((always_inline))`. In MSVC you can use `__forceinline`

Comment: @R..: I hate to disagree, but that's actually not entirely accurate. In C++ language `inline` does not affect the linkage either. Inline functions in C++ still have *external* linkage by default. At least that's the way it is in C++98 and C++03. In C++ you need to do `static inline` to force internal linkage on an inline function. If the C++ compiler decided not to generate the body for this inline function, it is not because of linkage. The linkage is external in this case. It must be something else. Global optimization of some sort?

Comment: Inline functions in C++ had internal linkage in some ancient version of C++ specification. But in C++98 they were given external linkage by default and it remained that way since that day.

Comment: Perhaps it doesn't affect what the language of the C++ spec calls "linkage", but it has some sort of ugly multiple-definition rule whereby the compiler is pretty much forced to output the "external" `inline` functions in their own sections so that at most one actually gets linked (and hopefully none get linked if it was inlined everywhere). The lack of diagnostic message probably has something to do with this mechanism.

Comment: @AndreyT Thanks for the discussion!  Can you point me to places in the C/C++ specifications where I can learn more?

Comment: The wording of the rule for C is probably ugly, but the contents of it is not so difficult. By default the compiler is free to use the given definition of the function to expand it at any calling site where it sees fit. And it is not allowed to produce a symbol, to avoid multiple-symbol-errors. To really force it to produce a symbol, you'd have to instantiate it in one compilation unit. This is not so different from C++, where you have to instantiate `inline` functions when you want to be sure that a symbol is produced for it.

Answer (score 1):

`inline` is only a suggestion, not something a compiler is obligated to listen to, so it can't assume that `foo` is not used in another compilation unit.

But, yeah, it would be nice to know exactly which is the undefined reference, given that you didn't post the error, and odd that it's shows up in C and not C++ compilation.

Comment: sorry I thought it was obvious that the undefined reference was for the pthread_setaffinity_np

Comment: Oh, that's a *linker* error you're getting, not a compile error. Are you sure you are linking in the correct library?

Comment: The entire point is that the C++ compiler pathway figured out that `foo` did not need to be included in the final binary, so the reference to the pthread library is unnecessary.  For some reason the C frontend didnt figure that out.  That's what I want to understand more about.

Answer (score 1):

`foo` might not be used in your source code, but it's almost certainly referenced elsewhere in the build process and consequently it needs to be compiled.

Especially since a lot of optimization occur in the linking process, because the linker can determine that a function is "dead" and can be discarded.

If, internally, the linker decides to assemble the entire program as one pass, and then optimization in another, I would expect you to see this error (how can it assemble the whole program?)

Further, if the function is to be exported then it most certainly has to be compiled, linked, and end up in the output.

It sounds like you're relying on compiler/linker specific behavior.