# Is it possible to completely disable the default C++ new operator?

Tags: c++, new-operator

Because our app has hard performance and memory constraints, our coding standards forbid the use of the default heap — ie, no `malloc`, no default `new`. Every memory allocation has to choose one of a few specific allocators; something like

```
// declared globally
void* operator new( size_t size, CustomAllocHeap* heap, const char* perpetrator_name )
{
  return heap->Allocate( size, perpetrator_name );
} 
// imagine a bunch of CustomAllocHeap's declared globally or statically, thus

Vector* v = new( gPhysicsHeap, __FUNCTION__ ) Vector( 1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f, 4.0f );
// or in a class
Thingy* p = new( this->LocalArenaHeap, __FUNCTION__ ) Thingy();
```

Although we've maintained good discipline on this with our code, some standard C++ components ( containers, `std::function` ) covertly make calls to the default `new` heap, which is very bad.

It would be nice to disable the default `new` altogether in some way, so that any line of code that implicitly results in a default allocation immediately throws a compiler error. That would let us notice these things right away.

We can obviously make `new` throw a runtime error *ie*

```
void* operator new ( size_t ) { __debugbreak(); return NULL; }
```

but it would be much better to get warnings about this at compile time. Is that possible?

Our app is built for a fixed platform (x64 with Visual Studio); portability is irrelevant.

Comment: Have you tried looking at linker output? I would think that you'd be able to tell from the linker map output whether the allocator routines are being called. It's not pointing at the offending line, but at least it would be able to break at build time.

Comment: an interesting pointer there: http://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/854450-there-any-way-disable-global-operator-new

Comment: is it an option to implement the default (all forms of) new/delete in terms of your custom new? I seem to remember it's possible to export new/delete using a .def file, resulting in the (entire?) process using the exported version.

Comment: @stijn nice idea but it would not allow detection at compile-time

Comment: @stijn That is precisely what `void* operator new ( size_t ) { __debugbreak(); return NULL; }` is about: it replaces the default new operator that is used by the process, it just needs to be linked in. So, the OP knows about this mechanism, and doesn't think it can be used to solve his problem.

Comment: well it was not entirely clear to me if the author really wants to disable use of eg std::function completely, or rather wants to be informed when it's used and then later on provide a fix for it. Reading the questoin again I guess it's the first option, but still not sure..

Comment: @stjin Unless there's a way to pass a parameter to `std::function` such that it calls `new ( CustomHeap *) (..)` instead of just default `new`, it has to be avoided altogether. And also things that implicitly make `std::function` in nonobvious ways need to be prevented too.

Comment: Are you sure that your runtime trick is going to work? I get `Error 1 error LNK2005: "void * __cdecl operator new(unsigned int)" (??2@YAPAXI@Z) already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR110D.dll)...TestLink.obj TestLink`

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: The C++ Standard explicitly allows replacing this function with a user-defined implementation, so it is required to work.  It might require changing some linker options though.

Answer (score 18):

You can implement the default `new` to call an unimplemented function. Then, at link time, you will get an error to the users of the bare `new` call:

```
#include <stdexcept>
inline void * operator new (std::size_t) throw(std::bad_alloc) {
    extern void *bare_new_erroneously_called();
    return bare_new_erroneously_called();
}
```

When I tested it on [IDEONE](http://ideone.com/tPMiXc), I got this error:

```
/home/geXgjE/ccrEKfzG.o: In function `main':
prog.cpp:(.text.startup+0xa): undefined reference to `bare_new_erroneously_called()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

In my tests, using `g++`, there is no link error if there are no references to the bare `new` in the program. This is because `g++` does not emit code for unused `inline` functions.

I don't have Visual Studio installed on my system, so the following information is just based on some documentation I have found. In order to get the inlined `new` operator to be seen everywhere, you should put its definition in a header file, and then use the [`/FI detect_bare_new.h`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8c5ztk84.aspx) option in your compiler.<sup>*</sup> According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6137734/315052), Visual Studio will not generate code for unused `inline` functions (like `g++`). However, you should check to see if there is an optimization level that needs to be enabled for that behavior or not.

> <sub>* `g++` has a similar compiler option: `-include detect_bare_new.h`.</sub>

This assumes that you intend to pass your own allocators to C++ templates and classes in the standard C++ library. If you do not, then inlined code in the standard headers that call the default allocator (which will call `new`) will trigger the linking error as well. If you wish to allow the standard C++ library to use the default `new`, then an easy way to make it work (at the expense of longer compile times) is to add all the standard C++ headers you intend to include at the top of the `detect_bare_new.h` file.

You state that portability of the solution is not important to you. But for the sake of completeness, I should highlight the issue that Ben Voigt correctly points out: The C++ standard does not guarantee the behavior of not generating code for unused `inline` functions. So, one may get a linking error even if the function is not used. But, if the code has no other references to the unimplemented function except within the stubbed `new` implementation, the error would be within the `new` definition itself. For example, `g++` could generate an error like:

```
/home/QixX3R/cczri4AW.o: In function `operator new(unsigned int)':
prog.cpp:(.text+0x1): undefined reference to `bare_new_erroneously_called()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

If your system is one that generates code for unused `inline` functions, you may still have a workaround. The workaround will work if the linker will report all erroneous references to the undefined function. In that case, if the only linking error observed is due to the definition of the `new` operator itself, there are no unexpected calls to the bare `new`. After verifying that the code only has that single error, you could then change the link line to include an object or library that has an appropriate definition of `bare_new_erroneously_called()` that would throw a runtime exception.

Comment: Are you sure this is legal according to the standard? [Answers to this question suggest that it may not be legal](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7297158/335858).

Comment: Since `operator new` isn't a template, this will cause an error whether it is called or not.  http://ideone.com/3KwAya

Comment: @BenVoigt There is a prototype for the function, so the compiler won't complain. And I guess you can sort the arguments to the linker in such a way, that it will realize that it doesn't need the new operator and doesn't go looking for the unimplemented function.

Comment: @BenVoigt Would anything change if you declare your operator `new` inline?

Comment: @BenVoigt: `inline` seems to address the linking error if it is not called.

Comment: @jxh: On one particular toolchain and set of compiler and linker options, perhaps, but that's not Standard behavior.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: I am certain it is syntactically correct to write code that calls a declared function. Actually calling a function that is never defined would cause undefined behavior, of course.

Comment: @jxh: There's nothing wrong with the syntax, but the function is odr-used and you haven't provided a definition.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Yes, that would generate the linking error. I was thinking of the case it linked anyway (because the `weak` attribute got attached to it).

Comment: @BenVoigt: I have reworded the answer to spell out the linking concerns.

Comment: I suppose you could also (instead of calling a function that is not there) static_assert (boost or standard, according to your compilers capabilities) and put in `false` as condition.

Comment: @TobiasLangner: The `static_assert` set to `false` fails as soon as the compiler sees the `static_assert`. What is wanted is a compilation failure when a bare `new` is used. My solution is to cause a link failure when a bare `new` is used.

Answer (score 4):

[Poison it!](https://github.com/leafsr/gcc-poison)
If you are using GCC, there is a pragma for this:

```
#ifdef __GNUC__

/* poision memory functions */
#   pragma GCC poison malloc new

#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

If your own "new" operator is not named "new" but differently (e.g. "myNew") you could use a "#define" in a way replacing "new" by rubbish:

```
#define new *+-/&
```

The pre-compiler would now replace a "new":

```
x = new mytype;
```

By the rubbish:

```
x = *+-/& mytype;
```

The advantage compared to a message at linking time is that this will generating a compiler message immediately while compiling the C++ file, not in the end when linking. You also see the line where the "new" is located.

The disadvantage is that you'll have to "#include" the file containing this "#define" in all C++ files in your project.

Comment: I don't know if this will work when linking against pre-compiled libs

Comment: @DanF: Usually, coding standards don't extend to third-party libraries provided in pre-compiled form. A non-inline version of my suggestion (and an extension of it that covers `malloc()` and friends) could detect if the library is using dynamic allocation, but the only solution then would be to override `malloc()` and `new()` itself with different behavior, or recompile modified versions of the offending libraries.

Comment: But this will also break `new (g_SpecificAllocator) Thingy()` which we *do* use.

Answer (score 1):

You can just declare operator new `= delete`, similar to how you'd disable some constructors. Like

```
struct Foo {
    void* operator new(std::size_t) = delete;
    void* operator new[](std::size_t) = delete;
};
```

That'll give you compiler errors when you try to use `new` with this class. See https://godbolt.org/z/RToOcf